# add event on controls - how can i refer to the control itself

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I want to add the same event on my multiple textboxes. Let's say for example I want all my textboxes to trim the text value of itself when it has lost focus

my idea is to loop through all the textboxes and to add an event handler to all of it, but how will I refer to the textbox itself, I think it is the same as using the "this" keyword, but it is not available in vb.net - any other recommendations?

Comment: Vb.net has `Me`, instead of `this`

Comment: @AndrewBarber, yes It has Me, but it refers to the current form. can I use the "Me" to refer to the current textbox?

Comment: Where did it go wrong? All you need is a basic `For Each` statement. However, if the controls are parented to different controls then it gets a bit more complicated.

Comment: What platform are you using? Is it ASP.NET, Windows forms, WPF, something else?

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå, I can already add events on multiple textboxes. but in order to trim it's text, I need to refer to the current textbox . how can I refer to the currently selected textbox?

Comment: Prepare an array of the textboxes that you want to handle and loop over this array. If you want to add a generic event handler to each one you don't need to know exactly which textbox

Comment: @Steve, so the only way is to make a control array? I was thinking if there are some other simpler methods, cause i want to avoid using control array .

Comment: @johnkernelle VB.NET is a language and you can use it for web, Windows forms, WPF or something else. The details of an answer can depend on what you are trying to do. What are you building?

Comment: No if your code should react one by one to a generic TextBox event there is a simpler method shown in an answer below. If you want to create some kind of global code that works on many textboxes (to initialize them, to read their values) without specifying the exact textbox then you need an array

Comment: @dotnetom, sorry, I do not know, I am new to visual studio development - I think it is windows form visual basic. by the way, thanks for your answer

Comment: @Steve, thanks for your time, I think the answer provided by dotnetom is the answer that i was looking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the element which triggered the event you can use the `sender` parameter of the event and cast it to the required type. It is not clear from the question which platform you are using, but below is the sample code for Windows Forms:

```
Private Sub txt1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txt1.TextChanged
    Dim currentTextbox as TextBox = CType(sender, TextBox)
    ' Do what you want with the textbox
End Sub
```

Similar principles should apply to Web forms or WPF as well.

Answer (score 1):

Through all the textboxes Use handles for all textboxes

```
Private Sub TextBox1_LostFocus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
    Handles TextBox1.LostFocus, TextBox2.LostFocus
    Dim txtBox As TextBox = sender
    txtBox.Text = Strings.Trim(txtBox.Text)
End Sub
```